# Не получается сохранить количество товара при добавлении в корзину

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Я пытаюсь создать корзину покупок для интернет-магазина. На странице товара находится кнопка "Add to cart", по нажатию на которую создается `line_item` и добавляется в `cart`.

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы на этой же странице рядом с кнопкой я мог выбрать количество товара, добавляемого в `line_item`, а затем и в `cart`, соответственно.

Код контроллера

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]

  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new
  end

  def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product)
    @line_item.quantity = params['q'].to_i

    if @line_item.save
      redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Item added to cart.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end    

  private

  def line_item_params
    params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id, :quantity)
  end
end
```

Код представления view/products/show.html.erb

```
<section class="section instrument-show">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-8">
      <h1 class="title is-2"><%= @product.title %></h1>            
      <h3 class="subtitle is-4">Description</h3>
      <%= @product.description %>
    </div>    

    <div class="column is-3 is-offset-1">
      <div class="bg-white pa4 border-radius-3">
        <h4 class="title is-5 has-text-centered"><%= number_to_currency(@product.price) %></h4>

        <form>
          <input type="number" name="q" min="1" max="50" step="1" class="input label">
        </form>


        <%= button_to 'Add to cart', line_items_path(product_id: @product), class: 'button is-warning add-to-cart' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</section>
```

При таком варианте кода в контроллере в `params['q']` я получаю "nil", а после `.to_i` - ноль. Почему форма

```
<form>
  <input type="number" name="q" min="1" max="50" step="1" class="input label">
</form>
```

не передаёт в контроллер этот параметр?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто-нибудь как мне в `LineItemsController` получить вводимое на странице товара число (количество покупаемого товара).

---

Метод add_product

```
  def add_product(product)
    current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product.id)

    if current_item
      current_item.increment(:quantity)
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product.id)
    end
    current_item
  end
```

Comment: У контроллера никаких шансов получить этот параметр, потому что форма "висит в воздухе" и никак не связана с кнопкой 'Add to cart'. Добавьте пожалуйста к вопросу метод `add_product`, попробую вам помочь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать так, чтобы кнопка "Add to cart" отправляла форму

```
<%= form_with model: LineItem.new, local: true  %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :product_id, value: @product.id %>
  <%= form.number_field :quantity, min: 1, max: 50, step: 1, class: "input label" %>
  <%= form.submit 'Add to cart', class: "button is-warning add-to-cart" %>
<% end %>
```

Теперь параметр `quantity` попадает в параметры контроллера и с ним можно работать. Он у вас уже есть в permitted params, проще всего ими и воспользоваться для создания нового `line_item`

```
def create
  @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(line_item_params)

  if @line_item.save
    redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Item added to cart.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Вы гений!!! Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: @StepanAnifer Всегда пожалуйста, заходите ещё :)